# Application Rollback possibilities in CF

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am reading the CF documentation on Rollback possibilities  and found these types of Rollback possibilities.

1. Application Rollback possibility [using Revisions](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/revisions.html#push-app)
2. Rollback to a [Previous Droplet](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/push-sub-commands.html#update-system-example)

My questions are:

1. I understand that *an app deployed with a new droplet*, will create a new `Revision` .This is like a 1:1 relationship between *droplet id* and *app revision* (however new app revisions could be created for reasons other than droplet change) .  Is this understanding correct ?
2. In which real life cases we should use droplet rollback option vs app revision rollback option?
3. Is there any other type of rollback beyond these 2 options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I understand that an app deployed with a new droplet, will create a new Revision .This is like a 1:1 relationship between droplet id and app revision (however new app revisions could be created for reasons other than droplet change) . Is this understanding correct ?

Yes. The [API docs for the Revision resource](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.113.0/index.html#revisions) explains this well.

> Revision are created when the following is changed:
>
> - A new droplet is created for an app
> - An app’s environment variables are changed
> - The custom start command for an app is added or changed
> - An app rolls back to a prior revision

Minor note. [The Revision resource is listed as experimental](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.113.0/index.html#experimental-resources) at the moment I write this. If you're interested in using this you're going to want to verify that your deployed version of CF is new enough to contain these capabilities.

> 2. In which real life cases we should use droplet rollback option vs app revision rollback option?

I would say that if you have a new enough version of CF deployed to use the revision functionality, that is going to be more full-featured. It has more capabilities and you can roll back more different scenarios.

Any reasonably new version of CF should be able to rollback droplets.

Rolling back droplets also requires a stop of the application, i.e. downtime, while revisions use the deployment capability of CF which can perform rolling deploys for no downtime.

> 3. Is there any other type of rollback beyond these 2 options ?

You could always orchestrate something on your own. Not sure I'd recommend doing that. The APIs are there, so you could script a process if one of these does not work for you.

An example of this. Before there were rolling deployments in CF. The common practice was to push a new application & move the routes to the new application (called blue/green deployment). This is because you could stage & start the new app & make sure it's working well, and then move the routes over to the new app. Moving routes is an instant operation on CF, so it worked well to manage applications without downtime. You could still do this, but using rolling deployments is recommended now.